# How to get indexes of all duplicate elements by using java stream

Tags: java, stream

For example, we have

```
List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(312, 312, 195, 195, 195, 851, 335, 851, 99);
```

I could group same elements like this

```
result = input.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(input::indexOf))
//result = {0=[312, 312], 2=[195, 195, 195], 5=[851, 851], 6=[335], 8=[99]}
```

But i want get result like this

```
{312=[0, 1], 195=[2, 3, 4], 851=[5, 7]}
```

or just like this

```
(0,1,2,3,4,5,7)
```

Cant' understand, how to do this.
Thx for attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Use `IntStream`

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = IntStream.range(0, input.size())
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> input.get(i), HashMap::new,
                        Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)));

// output : {99=[8], 851=[5, 7], 195=[2, 3, 4], 312=[0, 1], 335=[6]}
```

Once you have all the values and their indexes you can simply filter out the entries which have more than 1 value.

 Full example:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = IntStream.range(0, input.size())
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> input.get(i), HashMap::new,
                        Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue().size()>1)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: great, thx! it's give me fresh lookup on streams, and will help to lean it better

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using `Collections.frequency`

```
int[] dupIndexes = IntStream.range(0, input.size())
                            .filter(i -> Collections.frequency(input, input.get(i)) > 1)
                            .toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's quite easy to solve by just for loop. Just keep a `Map` with input value as a key and it's index as a value of map:

```
Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<>();
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
    if (map.containsKey(input.get(i))) {
        result.add(map.get(input.get(i)));
        result.add(i);
    } else {
        map.put(input.get(i), i);
    }
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Output

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code -

```
     List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(312, 312, 195, 195, 195, 851, 335, 851, 99));
    result = IntStream.range(0, input.size()).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(input::get, HashMap::new,
                    Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> ls = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        if (map.get(input.get(i)) != null) {
            ls = map.get(input.get(i));
        } else {
            ls = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }
        ls.add(i);
        map.put(input.get(i), ls);
    }
    System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: sorry dude, but i searching stream solution (on studying practice)
and i find it in answers

Comment: no worries,  glad you got your solutions & I too learned few new things,